# What kind of symptoms does a worn engine show?

Tags: engine

I don't have a specific problem with my car, but it is a Fiat Punto with 110000 miles on the clock. I was wondering what sort of problems may start to appear as the engine racks up further mileage.

I don't know how many miles an engine should be able to bear (assuming proper servicing), or what the signs might be that it is starting to fail so I'm not confident I'd be able to spot problems early in order to take it in for a more thorough inspection.

Clutches and brakes have "tells" that they are wearing out. Are there some similar things for the engine unit as a whole?

Comment: Lack pf power, excessive smoke, rough running...

Comment: Caused by worn valve seats and rings ( re : @Solar Mike)